# Summation notation -1 in front of sigma

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm not sure how to read the notation in the question I am given.[image]

My problem is with the -1 in front of the summation notation does this mean inverse of sum? Subtract 1 from the sum? I have no idea.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: No, it just means that the upper limit for the sum is
$$2^{j+1}-1$$
In other words, the values of $n$ to be used are, successively,
$$n = 2^j,\;\;n=2^j+1,\;\;n = 2^j+2,\;...,\;n=2^{j+1}-1$$

Comment: It means you're subtracting $1$ from $2^{j+1}$. In other words, the upper limit is $2^{j+1} - 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means this $$\sum_{n=2^j}^{2^{j+1}-1}\frac1n>\sum_{n=2^j}^{2^{j+1}-1}\frac1{2^{j+1}}$$ i.e. the $-1$ is part of the upper limit.